# How do i show a static page before taking a user to my node app on openshift?

Tags: node.js, express, openshift

I want to show a simple index.html page before taking my user to my chat app (via a "Start chatting" button).

Right now it seems openshift defaults my webpage to serve the chat.html page instead.

My main.js code

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/chat.html');
});

app.set('port', process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_PORT || 8080);
app.set('ip', process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_IP || '127.0.0.1');

http.listen(app.get('port'), app.get('ip'), function () {
    console.log('Listening on port ' + app.get('port'));
});
//... More code
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will make yoursite.com return the index.html page:

```
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});
```

This will make yoursite.com/chat return the chat.html page

```
app.get('/chat', function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/chat.html');
});
```

You can then add a link from your index.html page to your chat.html page.

Within index.html:

```
<a href="./chat.html" class="btn btn-info" role="button">Go To Chat</a>
```

See express documentation for more details on routing: [Express Routing](http://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html)

Comment: Ohhhh, i see! Alright, let me try that and i'll get back to you. Thanks in advance :)